# How to enter special characters like "&" in oracle database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to insert special character `&` in my insert statement. My insert is:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(name, class_id) VALUES ('Samantha', 'Java_22 & Oracle_14');
```

If I try to run this query I am getting a popup and it asks me to enter value for `Oracle_14`.

How can I enter special characters like `&` in the insert statement for oracle db?

Comment: Which tool are you using to perform the insert?

Comment: I am using SQLDeveloper.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you are in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, you want to run

```
SQL> set define off;
```

before executing the SQL statement.  That turns off the checking for substitution variables.

SET directives like this are instructions for the client tool (SQL*Plus or SQL Developer).  They have session scope, so you would have to issue the directive every time you connect (you can put the directive in your client machine's glogin.sql if you want to change the default to have DEFINE set to OFF).  There is no risk that you would impact any other user or session in the database.

Comment: 17 seconds... I was *so* close

Comment: so will this only turn defination off for my sql or for the complete table or complete database also can i have something like this in production insert script ?

Comment: IMO, your production code should be *using* substitution, or at minimum, handling it itself. I believe that code does the setting for your login session, though.

Comment: @Rachel - SET commands are client directives that have session scope.  The database has no idea what directives, if any, you've given your client so it has no impact on a table or on any other database session.

Comment: @OMG Ponies- Sweet, sweet vengeance for all the times you've beaten me :-)

Comment: @Justin: but in that case, lets say if am running the insert script with set directive off in production than will it be only for one insert or for the complete list of inserts for that particular session, can explain a little more on this, am only concern is `should i have set directive off in the insert script which will be running on production ?`

Comment: @Rachel - It's perfectly fine to SET DEFINE OFF in a production script, yes.  It will affect all the other statements running in the same session (you could, of course, SET DEFINE ON later in the script if you wanted to).  But it would generally be unusual to have substitution variables in a script running in production-- you normally don't want production scripts to prompt the user for information, you normally want that to be part of the script.

Comment: @Justin: Thanks Justin for Clarification.

Answer (score 27):

Try `'Java_22 '||'&'||' Oracle_14'`

Answer (score 22):

Justin's answer is the way to go, but also as an FYI you can use the chr() function with the ascii value of the character you want to insert.  For this example it would be:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(name, class_id) VALUES ('Samantha', 'Java_22 '||chr(38)||' Oracle_14');
```

Answer (score 7):

you can simply escape & by following a dot. try this:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(name, class_id) VALUES ('Samantha', 'Java_22 &. Oracle_14');
```

Comment: But this will insert "." as well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

To Insert values which has got '&' in it. Use the folloiwng code.

```
Set define off;

Begin

INSERT INTO STUDENT(name, class_id) VALUES ('Samantha', 'Java_22 & Oracle_14');

End ;
```

And Press F5 from Oracle or Toad Editors.

Answer (score 1):

We can use another way as well
for example to insert the value with special characters 'Java_22 & Oracle_14' into db we can use the following format..

```
'Java_22 '||'&'||' Oracle_14'
```

Though it consider as 3 different tokens we dont have any option as the handling of escape sequence provided in the oracle documentation is incorrect.

Comment: Thats's what EternalNoob said, and close to what Craig said, when the question was first asked.

Comment: Not sure why this is not the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to do so :

1) Simply do SET DEFINE OFF; and then execute the insert stmt.

2) Simply by concatenating reserved word within single quotes and concatenating it.
E.g. Select 'Java_22 ' || '& '|| ':' || ' Oracle_14' from dual --(:) is an optional.

3) By using CHR function along with concatenation.
E.g. Select 'Java_22 ' || chr(38)||' Oracle_14' from dual

Hope this help !!!

Answer (score 0):

If an escape character is to be added at the beginning or the end like `"JAVA"`, then use:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(name, class_id) VALUES ('Samantha', ''||chr(34)||'JAVA'||chr(34)||'');
```

Answer (score 0):

For special character set, you need to check UNICODE Charts. After choose your character, you can use sql statement below,

```
SELECT COMPOSE('do' || UNISTR('\0304' || 'TTTT')) FROM dual;
```

--

d**ō**TTTT

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use concat like this :D

```
Insert into Table Value(CONCAT('JAVA ',CONCAT('& ', 'Oracle'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strAdd=strAdd.replace("&","'||'&'||'");
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I need to insert a row with text 'Please dial *001 for help'.
In this case the special character is an asterisk.

By using direct insert using sqlPlus it failed with error "SP2-0734: unknown command beginning ... "

I tryed set escape without success.

To achieve, I created a file insert.sql on filesystem with

```
insert into testtable (testtext) value ('Please dial *001 for help');
```

Then from sqlPlus I executed

```
@insert.sql
```

And row was inserted.

Answer (score -4):

You can either use the backslash character to escape a single character or symbol

> 'Java_22 \& Oracle_14'

or braces to escape a string of characters or symbols

> '{Java_22 & Oracle_14}'

Comment: your first approach does not work.

Comment: It prints bracket too for second approach and `\&` for first approach.

Comment: Anonymous user says: *Remark: this is originally instructed in Oracle documentation but not working in client like SQL Developer.*