# how to insert the '&' character into data base from java

Tags: java, sql, web-services

I am using the webservice that will send the request for one of the column as Dran & Hyle ,   but i get the exception as a expected valid begining name character. due to the special  character &

Below is the insert statement in my java .

```
    public static final String PetInsert= insert into pet values(?,?,?);
```

I believe set define off will not work in java code , it is understood only by sql developer.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where is your code? Where is the exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175431/how-to-enter-special-characters-like-in-oracle-database

Comment: i get the exception as ' ' expect a valid beginning name character

Comment: what is your code? what is your error? how your table looks like?

Answer (score 0):

From `Java`, it is recommended to use `PreparedStatement` when creating a statement to query the database. Read more in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: yes thanks for the reply! i have used the prepared statement as  PreparedStatement test= connection.prepareStatement(Constants.PetInsert) and i am able to insert the values into the database, but when i try to insert the value into the database for special chracters it throws me such kind of exception, hence i wanted to know how to insert the special characters like '&' into the database

Comment: Try to edit the original post and add the full exception stack. Also, specify the database driver you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure, but can it be that in the XML of the web service the error is located? Then somewhere

```
"Dran &amp; Hyle"
```

should go into the XML. Normally it is done automatically. So it would be the unlikely case of creating the XML oneself with Strings.

In that case use apache's StringEscapeUtils:

```
s = StringEscapeUtils.escaleXML(s);
```

P.S. I found `set define off` of @aUserHimself plausible.