# Use special character '%' to append the string in update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to update a table where the table column is of `varchar2` datatype and need to update the value of columns with `'%'`.

for example --

```
create table test (id number, name varchar2(20));

insert into test values (1, 'smith');
insert into test values (2, 'allen');
```

Now we need to update the values in NAME column to smith'%'

So it should also include the single quotes in the string.

I am able to update it to smith% but it should be smith'%'

```
update test
  set name = 'smith'||'''%'''
where id = 1;
```

> SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: The update should not be failing AFAIK.  Are you sure this is the actual query you ran?

Comment: i think '%' is not that character || is

Comment: It worked for me. @TimBiegeleisen is right. Are you sure you ran the query ok?

Comment: @pablomatico Perhaps Oracle has some mode where concatenation using `||` is not possible?

Comment: Hmm, maybe... Where are you running the update statement?

Comment: Your example doesn't even need the concatenation: `'smith''%'''` will do just fine. But I guess what you _meant_ is `set name = name||'''%'''`: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fbf0f2654ddccb165c991c3cee6719f2

Comment: Which client are you using, in case that matters? The only way I can see you getting that error from what you posted is if you had done `set sqlterminator off`` or the equivalent for your client, but that would affect all statements, not just one that has a % in it. Are you maybe calling this from some shell or script that is interpreting the % before it reaches Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

SQL> set define off;

verify this link

[how-to-enter-special-characters-like-in-oracle-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175431/how-to-enter-special-characters-like-in-oracle-database)

Comment: This doesn't affect how % is handled. There are no ampersands in the OP's question.

Comment: all comes under special char

Comment: `set define off` has nothing to do with the `%` sign.

Answer (score 1):

Your query works perfectly in SQLPlus:

```
SQL> update test
  2    set name = 'smith'||'''%'''
  3  where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 smith'%'
         2 allen
```

This could  be another way, avoiding the need to double the quotes:

```
SQL> update test
  2    set name = 'allen'|| q'['%']'
  3  where id = 2;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 smith'%'
         2 allen'%'
```

Or even, avoiding the `||`:

```
SQL> update test
  2    set name = concat(name, q'['%']')
  3  where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 smith'%''%'
         2 allen'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your statement should work, I just tested it in my database.

```
update test
  set name = concat('smith', '''%''')
where id = 1;
```